# Is it fair if professor doesn't meet the deadline but asks students to submit more than a week before?

Tags: ethics

My professor asked me to submit a report more than a week before the official deadline. Other professors were more lenient to their students. I submitted my report on the deadline as told by him. However, he himself did not send me some documents that were required to be sent before the deadline.

This didn't happened for the first time. Multiple times I have seen that my professor didn't follow the official rules but expected me to do work according to official rules, which I did.

I find this really discriminatory. Isn't everyone expected to follow the rules ? Why only the students?  I also see other professors following the rules.

Answer (score 4):

This isn’t an issue of fairness or discrimination. The professor is expected to follow the rules that apply to him, and you are expected to follow the rules that apply to you. Both of those things are true independently of each other. If the professor were lenient with you about your deadline, that would not make it more appropriate for him to violate a deadline imposed on him by the university, or other official rules.

It’s perfectly reasonable to complain to your university about the professor not treating you according to the rules of the institution. Your complaint would be justified, and I hope acted on, regardless of whether you yourself are a rule-abiding person.

Comment: By saying that he didn't followed the rules, I mean that he didn't helped me in anyway like providing feedback or something. He didn't followed a lot of rules which could have helped me in doing better. So isn't he doing wrong with me then ?

Comment: @The_Mike You should reframe this. It's not about some kind of injustice. You would like their behavior to change. You should be asking how to best achieve that.

Comment: @The_Mike it sounds like he’s just bad at his job. There are plenty of people like that. It’s unfortunate, and certainly justified for you to complain about. But being bad at your job isn’t the same thing as not following the rules. It’s important to describe your problem in accurate terms so that people can understand what you’re taking about and don’t dismiss you as a person who complains unreasonably about pointless things.

Comment: @DanRomik Problem is if I complain then it's more likely that his colleagues (who will decide injustice) would support him. I see in most cases colleagues support each other. However there is no subjectivity in my case. I mean I am clearly right and he is wrong.

Comment: @The_Mike not all problems have an easy solution. But what’s certain is if you don’t complain, nothing will change.

Comment: @DanRomik Okay. Unfortunately many students are afraid of professors for grade related things. I am not. I will seek justice.